# Is there any way to make checkbox browser independent?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make checkboxs plain and consistent across browsers. Which basically means I don't want browsers to apply their native style for checkbox element.

**Also I don't want to use any plugin that replaces checkbox with image and does the stuff.**

Is it possible to achieve it by overriding default CSS or something?

Comment: from CodePen: http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp just followup on that example. Keep in mind it's CSS3, so, any browser without that capability will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right , you can mimic checkbox like this:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9eafv435/1/)

Here i'm using font awesome to present V symbol inside the checkbox when it checked.

First of all we hide real checkbox, then we define label and associate it with our checkbox using `for="simpleCheckbox"` attribute of the label, we need this in order to be able to click on label which get focus and send it to real checkbox to be checked , then using `:before` pseudo-element we define our custom looking checkbox  .

HTML:

```
<div class="visual-checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="simple-checkbox" name="simpleCheckbox" id="simpleCheckbox"  />
        <label class="visual-checkbox" for="simpleCheckbox">
            Check Me If You Dare !
        </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.visual-checkbox-container {
  margin: 20% 5%;
}

.simple-checkbox {
 display: none;
}

 .visual-checkbox {
 width: 11em;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
}

  .visual-checkbox:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 border-radius: 25%;
 box-shadow: .4px 1px 3px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.71) inset, -.5px -.4px 3px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.40) inset;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 }

  .visual-checkbox:focus:before , .visual-checkbox:hover:before {
 box-shadow: .5px .5px 2px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.70),  -.5px -.5px 2px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.70) , .2px .5px 3px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.90) inset, -.5px -.2px 3px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.90) inset;
 }


 .simple-checkbox:checked + .visual-checkbox:before {
 box-shadow: .5px .5px 2px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.76),  -.5px -.5px 2px 0 rgba(72, 217, 91, 0.76);
 background-color: rgba(78, 183, 91, 0.90);
}

.simple-checkbox:checked + .visual-checkbox:after {
 font-family:  FontAwesome;
 content: "\f00c";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 color:  #fff;
 font-size: .9em;
 }
```

Of course design could be done different .

Comment: @Konurd  Thanks for the answer, but if I run the fiddle in Chrome and Firefox, both show me different checkbox style, in FF little darker and in chrome lighter

Comment: @Abhi, you right , i've deleted `border: .5px solid rgba(58, 138, 68, 0.96);` from `.visual-checkbox:before` now it looks the same in Chrome and FF. I updated the link in the JSFiddle, check it out.